# XPath Y if XPath X contains string Z

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to apply XPath query X if some XPath query Y contains some string Z?

HTML

```
<div class="pluto">
   <ul>
       <li>apples</li>
       <li>oranges</li>
   </ul>
   Success
</div>
```

Something like XPath:

```
//div[@class='pluto']/text() IF contains(//div/ul/li[1], "apples")
```

Output

```
Success
```

Comment: It's XPath, like XQuery, not like iPhone. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just bringing the condition to the expression:

```
//div[@class='pluto'][contains(//div/ul/li[1], "apples")]/text()
```

Will return `Sucess` only if that contition is met. Otherwise the result will be empty.

On a side note, what you really seem to search could be simplified:

```
//div[@class='pluto'][contains(ul/li[1], "apples")]/text()
```

Once again, it will only bring results if the `contains` condition is met.

In **XPath 2.0**, on the other hand, if you need a **value depending on your condition** and not the node value itself, you can use a **`if` expression**:

```
if (//div[@class='pluto'][contains(ul/li[1], "apples")]/text()) then 'OK!' else 'NOT OK!'
```

Which will bring the `then` part (`'OK!'`) if it finds a match and the `else` part `('NOT OK!')` if finds nothing.

### Update:

> What if I would like to execute another xPath query if the condition is NOT met (kind of like an else-if)?

You can put any XPath expression in the `then` or `else` part:

```
if (//div[@class='pluto'][contains(ul/li[1], "apples")]/text())
then
concat('OK! :',//div/ul/li[1])
else
concat('NOT OK! :',//div/ul/li[2])
```

#### If-then-else Using XPath 1.0:

```
concat(
  substring(concat('OK! :',    //div/ul/li[1])       , 1, number(    boolean(count( //div[@class='pluto'][contains(ul/li[1], "apples")]/text() )))  * string-length( concat('OK! :',    //div/ul/li[1]) )),
  substring(concat('NOT OK! :',//div/ul/li[2])       , 1, number(not(boolean(count( //div[@class='pluto'][contains(ul/li[1], "apples")]/text() )))) * string-length( concat('NOT OK! :',//div/ul/li[2]) ))
)
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply! What if I would like to execute an different xPath query if the condition is NOT met? (using your first method, not the if-else method)

Comment: Thank you! However, the if-then-else statement used is not working b/c I am not on version 2.0 of xPath, I was trying to create an `else`-like condition using your very first method... `//div[@class='pluto'][contains(//div/ul/li[1], "apples")]/text()` I appreciate the help :)

Comment: I added an if-then-else using xpath 1.0. Please test it. If it works, I'll add an explanation!

Comment: Hum, it didn't? Did it give any error? Or gave an undesired result?

Comment: Also, did you change it or used the one I posted? If you changed, can you show the exact expression?